# How to load .mat file into workspace using Matlab Engine API for Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I have a .mat workspace file containing 4 character variables. These variables contain paths to various folders I need to be able to `cd` to and from relatively quickly. Usually, when using only Matlab I can load this workspace as follows (provided the .mat file is in the current directory).

```
load paths.mat
```

Currently I am experimenting with the Matlab Engine API for Python. The Matlab [help docs](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/use-the-matlab-engine-workspace-in-python.html) recommend using the following Python formula to send variables to the current workspace in the desktop app:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
x = 4.0
eng.workspace['y'] = x
a = eng.eval('sqrt(y)')
print(a)
```

Which works well. However the whole point of the .mat file is that it can quickly load entire ***sets*** of variables the user is comfortable with. So the above is not efficient when trying to load the workspace.

I have also tried two different variations in Python:

```
eng.load("paths.mat")
eng.eval("load paths.mat")
```

The first variation successfully loads a dict variable in Python containing all four keys and values but this does not propagate to the workspace in Matlab. The second variation throws an error:

> File "", line unknown SyntaxError: Error: Unexpected MATLAB
>   expression.

How do I load up a workspace through the engine without having to manually do it in Matlab? This is an important part of my workflow....

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the number of output arguments from the MATLAB engine, which is a possible reason for the error.

I would expect the error from `eng.load("paths.mat")` to read something like

> TypeError: unsupported data type returned from MATLAB

The difference in error messages may arise from different versions of MATLAB, engine API...

In any case, try specifying the number of output arguments like so,

```
eng.load("paths.mat", nargout=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was giving me fits for a while. A few things to try. I was able to get this working on Matlab 2019a with Python 3.7. I had the most trouble trying to create a string and using the string as an argument for load and eval/evalin, so there might be some trickiness with the single or double quotes, or needing to have an additional set of quotes in the string.

1. Make sure the MAT file is on the Matlab Path. You can use addpath and rmpath really easily with pathlib objects:

```py
from pathlib import Path

mat_file = Path('local/path/from/cwd/example.mat').resolve # get absolute path
eng.addpath(str(mat_file.parent))
# Execute other commands
eng.rmpath(str(mat_file.parent))
```

2. Per dML's answer, make sure to specify the nargout=0 when there are no outputs from the function, and always when calling a script. If there are 1 or more outputs you don't have to have an output in Python, and there is more than one it will be output as a tuple.
3. You can also turn your script into a function (just won't have access to base workspace without using evalin/assignin):

```py
function load_example_matfile()
  evalin('base','load example.mat')
end
```

```bash
eng.feval('load_example_matfile')
```

4. And, it does seem to work on the plain vanilla eval and load as well, but if you leave off the `nargout=0` it either errors out or gives you the output of the file in python directly.

Both of these work.

```py
eng.eval('load example.mat', nargout=0)
eng.load('example.mat', nargout=0)
```